# JavaScript replace all instances not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, replace

Chrome is failing to replace all instances of the '_' string with '/' and I'm not sure why. I've got the `g` global operator and `i` case-insensitive operator.

```
var sample_string = 'mail/contacts/add/';
var p0 = sample_string.replace('_','/','gi');
```

Comment: Did you mean `'mail_contacts_add_'`?

Comment: What you need is `/_/g` instead of `'_'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have mistaken something, either sample_string or replace call.

Second, flags are non standard and you should use regex with flags as first param instead flags as third param.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace